# Can't run "npm install expo-cli --global"

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I am a newbie in all this stuff. Hope for your understanding.

Let me clarify the issue:
I am trying to start react native app through expo cli. So tried to start `npm install expo-cli --global` to install npm globally. I got these errors:

- [Screen_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBtMJ.png)
- [Screen_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALZU5.png)

It also says that I lack permissions to access it. How can I allow permissions?
Even when I try to start it locally I got the same issue. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7.......

Comment: open start > search for cmd > right click on cmd and click `run as administrator` > Now `npm i -g expo-cli` this should work.

Comment: Ok. Will try it. Thanks:))

Comment: @Rajendran Nadar thanks, this worked for me! :)

Comment: I used this `npm install --global expo-cli ` and  it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

although this solution is not the best and the safest solution exists, this worked for me and that make sense because all the problem we had with the errors is the permission problems. so you can use this command and ignore those permission problems :

```
sudo npm install expo-cli -g --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: It is worked for me. It saved my time. Thanks a lot

Comment: the cmd npm install -g expo-cli after the updated version of npm is still not working for me, it is showing this error ```[            ......] | remove:@expo/config: sill remove C:\Users\jagan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config``` please solve this

Comment: new error ```Installing Expo CLI failed. You can install it manually with:
  npm install --global expo-cli
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294963248
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jagan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-29T06_08_01_926Z-debug.log```

Comment: Note that this is no longer valid - the `expo` package now provides the CLI. `npm install expo`

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same problem with npm install -g expo-cli, having "MODULE_NOT_FOUND",

I installed yarm with brew, just in case you do not already have it:

```
brew install yarn
```

and then use:

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

to create a project you can:

```
expo init nameOfTheNewProject
```

and choose a template in the console.
Finally run the project with

```
yarn start
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for respond. 

This caused by the yarn issue on window OS which could not download the git URL, I reinstalled the git and set the PATH environment then it fixed.

Comment: Hi, happy to know it !

Comment: thank you yarn global add expo-cli solved my install error

Comment: Thank you very much! This resolved my error.

Answer (score 6):

You did not mention which os. This answer working for any operating system (ubuntu in my case)

I'm also getting permission errors when running

```
sudo npm install --global expo-cli
```

Which I don't really how this can happen - as this also happens for the superuser!

For me it works when I install the client locally into the project

```
cd <new-project-dir>
npm init # init npm project
npm install expo-cli
```

Now you can use the client in this project like this:

```
npx expo-cli # e.g. npx expo-cli init <project-name>
```

Comment: Ohh, It makes sense...Thank you so much)

Answer (score 3):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

This will solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

Try using `npm install -g expo-cli@3.5.0` this worked for me, it may work for you.

Comment: Thanks, its work for me, latest version was giving an error.

Comment: its gave me  this error msg :--  npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.3","validator":"10.'

Comment: use this command : npm cache clean --force then install it again and use sudo npm install -g expo-cli

Answer (score 2):

### Follow the steps

- First, run `npm cache verify`.
- Open Windows PowerShell as administrator and run `npm install expo-cli
  --global --no-optional` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command:

> npm install -g expo-cli

or,

> yarn global add expo-cli

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the command as administrator from a command prompt on windows and not bash. Had me stumpt for bloody ages!

Answer (score 1):

You need administrator privilege. So when you open command line interface, just **right click** and **run as administrator**

This will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this  issue comes from permission or node version , if you get this error when the node module is being refreshed ---> This is definitely a permission issue. Disable your Antiviruses or change permission manually check [this](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/191) as well.

Answer (score 1):

First run `npm cache verify`, then run `sudo npm install --global expo-cli`.

Did work for me indeed after trying so much.

Answer (score 1):

`npm cache clean --force` then `npm install --unsafe-perm -g expo-cli`

Comment: Are you aware of the risks of using sudo with npm? Did you disclose those risks in this answer?

Comment: While this post may answer the question, code-only answers are often considered low-quality. Please provide some rationale / text explanation as to why this is the correct answer, even if short.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user.
The best way to solve this problem is to reinstall npm with a node version manager.And you don't need to remove your current version.

## About node version manager

1. use nvm or n with OSX or Linux
2. use nodist or nvm-windows with windows

Comment: I will try and reply soon. Thanks

Comment: can you please share a link , about how to do that , please mention the procedure also.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Node version to +10

Then do

```
sudo npm install expo-cli -g
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I hope this would solve your problem!

```
sudo npm install expo-cli -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of the solutions above result in success, please follow the steps below:

1. Uninstall Node.js
2. Restart your pc/mac
3. Download latest version of the Node.js (https://nodejs.org/en/)
4. Open cmd as admin mode or use "sudo" before the command line on Mac.

   npm install expo-cli --global

I hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted two files then everything worked. The two files are in this path: `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming\npm` under the names 'expo.ps1' and 'expo-cli.ps1'

Then run:

```
npm i -g expo-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

re-install node.js, it works for me

Comment: When adding an answer to a question that already has fifteen other answers it is useful to point out what aspect of the question your answer addresses that has not already been addressed. Also it is useful to explain why you think your solution will work, and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

First update Node.js to the latest stable version and then again try to install expo ad clean before expo folders that are being created in below location

```
C:\Users\{{computer_username}}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

If it's throwing error in visual studio code, try from cmd, was facing same error but solved through this way

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Comment: i  am bot able to delete the expo-cli file in the location `C:\Users\{{computer_username}}\AppData\Roaming\npm` , it is always saying the folder is in use, even though i have closed all the folders.

Answer (score 0):

try going into windows resource monitor and terminating adb.exe (android resource bridge). This worked for me after searching for solutions for days. I tried this after verifying cache, clearing cache, you name it.

Answer (score 0):

As a Debian 10 buster user I got the same permission error while using this command: `sudo npm install expo-cli --global`.
The problem was solved by installing expo-cli with yarn package manager and the command below: `sudo yarn global add expo-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows User :-

Open your Powershell and type:

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

This worked for me after trying and reasearching for hours.

Note:Don't Use cmd or any other terminal and also don't type npm install expo-cli -g as it is written in the react native docs. It would always show up an npm error.

Answer (score 0):

**For windows**
*Follow these steps carefully*

1. open the `command prompt` and run it as `administrator`.
2. *recommended*  `npm uninstall --global expo-cli`.
3. run the command  `npm cache clean --force`.
4. run the command `npm cache verify` .
5. now run the command `npm install --global expo-cli`
6. dont run command like `npm i -g expo-cli` or  `npm install -g expo-cli`.

7.Make sure you run  the command mentioned in the **4th step ONLY**.

thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Windows 10, to be able to install the latest version (I had no choice since it broke the current one). I had to install the latest version of Python (3.8.0) and then run `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` as an administrator, then I was able to run again: `npm install expo-cli --global` to install the version 3.8.0 of the expo-cli

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution and 100% working. I am working with Windows and not sure abut Linux.

Open cmd and

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

then press yes

Now run the command to start your project

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I had previously removed Expo from my Windows machine and encountered this error whilst trying to reinstall. Reading the error message solved the problem.

```
npm i expo-cli -g --legacy-peer-deps
```

Using this command in 'PowerShell'  installed expo successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem here is my fix, go to Finder, in the input field (search box) type in /usr/local/lib then press CMD + SHIFT + G press the OK button or whatever pops up, then CMD + SHIFT + . and delete the NVM file i deleted the expo folder too. Then go to this link https://changelog.com/posts/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x
follow the instructions and install brew, node, etc. Last step go to your terminal and type sudo npm install expo-cli --global

Answer (score 0):

First: I upgraded my mac version 10.13 to 10.15

Then I downloaded homebrew, Watchman, Git and Node.js

Finally I ran this command `sudo npm install --global expo-cli --legacy-peer-deps`

If you have any further questions check the docs out: https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/installation/

Answer (score 0):

Sometime, I use npm not work.
I try a lots times run with npm but fail for  expo cli.
Please try `yarn global add expo-cli`
It wills save your time ^^.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install expo-cli with my company npm registry configured.
I've created 2 differents profiles using npmrc and using the profile with https://registry.npmjs.org/ solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me... ubuntu 20.02
sudo npm install expo-cli -global

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).