# Expo CLI installed through yarn, but not working

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg, expo

So I tried installing expo CLI for my react native project. I tried installing it with npm as shown on the official [expo.io](https://docs.expo.io/get-started/installation/) website, but it didn't work out. So as per the answers from this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55140179/11260996) post. It installed with the command `yarn global add expo-cli` and I got to see this following output.

```
success Installed "expo-cli@4.0.13" with binaries:
      - expo
      - expo-cli
```

but to verify whether the installation was successful, I ran the command `expo whoami` and got the following error.

```
Command 'expo' not found, did you mean:

  command 'exo' from snap exoscale-cli (v1.22.0)
  command 'expr' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)
  command 'expn' from deb sendmail-base (8.15.2-18)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I really don't know what's going on here and how can I get to run expo CLI successfully, a little help for your newbie fellow developer here.

Answer (score 1):

Check if expo-cli is properly installed or not using the following code:

```
yarn global list
```

Check if expo-cli is added to your path or not using the following code. (Generally, it should be added automatically )

```
echo $PATH
```

This will show a list of folders. Look into these folder and try to find expo-cli. If that is not present there then export the path of expo-cli in your .bashrc ( or other dotfile ) using the following

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/PATH/TO/YOUR/EXPOCLI
```

Change the "PATH/TO/YOUR/EXPOCLI" to the path of your expo-cli.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I already found a solution to my problem, I used the command yarn web and it workout fine. I'll try what you said, but I really think I'll be sticking with the yarn web command.

Comment: ok, try out other commands as well, like "yarn ios".
Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows, follow these steps:

1. Follow this guide to access the PATH environment variable https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-the-windows-path/
2. Add an entry to the Path environment variable that looks like this: `C:\Users\<YourUserNameHere>\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin`